# How do I nest ${} in gsp

Tags: gsp, grails

This is in my gsp and it doesn't work

```
<g:select name="head.id" from="${com.hive.Persons.findAllByFirstname(${variable})}" optionKey="id" value="${organizationInstance?.head?.id}"  />
```

I think that the main reason is that I am nesting ${}. How can I accomplish this.
${variable} is a string passed from the controller.

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the nested ${}

```
<g:select name="head.id" from="${com.hive.Persons.findAllByFirstname(variable)}" optionKey="id" value="${organizationInstance?.head?.id}"  />
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your `from` attribute should be populated in controller on the server side.
2. As a dirty hack you can use the following code:

> <g:findAll in="${com.hive.Persons.findAll()}" expr="it.firstname == ${variable}">
>
> ```
>   <option>${it.firstname}</option>
> ```
>
> </g:findAll>